# library-independent names for keyboard keys?

Tags: c++, c, keyboard

If you check portable libraries like [Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum) or [SDL](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Keycode), they all provide portable names for keyboard keys, but using those names in your applications binds you to a particular library. Does there exist a way to name keyboard keys without committing to any particular library? A standard or some repository of keyboard key names?

Comment: Your question is half off topic. First why tag C and C++ ? secondly, you are asking for off ressource site. That said in C++ you can do an interface to abstract the library you use and in C you can just use an `enum`. That said I will not advice to do that, it's quite useless, choice your library and code. If you need to change in the future, you will see that in the future. Don't over think about your maybe potential futur use...

Comment: Basically all the "portable" C/C++ GUI libraries use custom names for keys and they form a basis of portability to all other languages. I can't understand why there is no standard for these names.

Comment: Because the is no need for that, graphic library can't be swap like a sql data base, if you change of it you will need to recode all you graphic related code, so change the name of key is trivial in comparaison.

Comment: Not necessarily true, say you use some OpenGL glue library like SDL and glut, most of the code is OpenGL, but maybe you also need to do some key processing. Some people even used Qt as OpenGL glue, but that's a bit of an overkill, still... it did happen.